# Making a Slideshow Rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with a concept with a HTML5/jQuery slideshow system...

I want the images to constantly rotate, without stopping. The way I have it set up now is just going to the first image by changing the margin-left back to 0 when I run out of slides. I'd much rather have it continue indefinitely.

While I'm at it...Is there a way to read a property from the stylesheet? It'd be better if I could ask a user to point the script to the stylesheet and pull the sizing and stuff from there.

Demo: http://bearce.me/so/slideshow

Script (mainly focus on the CSS version, I can convert it to the jQuery version once I understand how to do it):

```
// JavaScript Document
var slides = 4; // number of slides
var time = 3; // time per slide (in seconds)
var width = 600; // width of slideshow (ex: 600)
var transition = .5 // transition time (in seconds) (for older browsers only, edit css for newer)
window.onload = function start() {
    if(Modernizr.csstransitions) {
        cssslide();
    } else {
        jqueryslide();
    }   
}
function cssslide() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.width=(width * slides) + "px";
    var num = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        num = (num + 1) % slides;
        document.getElementById('container').style.marginLeft = (("-" + width) * num) + "px"; 
    }, time * 1000);
}
function jqueryslide() {
    $("#container").width((width * slides) + 'px');
    var num = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        num = (num + 1) % slides;
        $("#container").animate({marginLeft: (("-" + width) * num) + "px"},{duration: (transition * 1000)});
    }, time * 1000);
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want it to constantly scroll, I want it to scroll, stop for a few seconds, scroll, stop, scroll, stop like it does, but instead of zooming all the way back  to the first image, I just want it to keep going.

Comment: There are plenty of "infinite" carousels already out there. Any reason to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I want a nice, easy to use HTML5 version. Plus I built this a while ago and I'd just like to finish it lol...

Comment: Ah, forgot I had posted that I guess. Anyway, it wasn't every answered properly

Answer (score 1):

When your slideshow initializes, use JS to duplicate your first image so that the markup looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="setup/slides/portal2.jpg" />
    <img src="setup/slides/crysis2.jpg" />
    <img src="setup/slides/deadspace2.jpg" />
    <img src="setup/slides/acb.jpg" />
    <img src="setup/slides/portal2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Then once the 5th slide (duplicate of slide 1) is visible, clear your interval, reset your margin to 0 and re-initialize your slideshow.

Comment: Ah, interesting idea. Only issue I think I'm going to run in to is that it's still going to transition, since I'm using CSS3 as the main animation. I don't think you can use `jQuery.css()` on CSS3 elements yet, since a lot of them still used vendor prefixes. I suppose I could just duplicate the entire set of images every time someone finishes the loop, if I can figure that out...

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously rethink your approach. Just tacking on more DOM elements into infinity is seriously inefficient, and would probably be an accessibility nightmare.

I would suggest you check out the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) - it's real easy to implement, and allows you to loop infinitely.

Comment: The point of the system is to use CSS3 transitions, so using jQuery Cycle doesn't seem to fit with what I'm looking for.